Charging circuit for Raspberry Pi Pico
Currently I am working on a kind of pager project. The main idea is that a base station communicates via LORA with my handheld, similar to a DECT phone (Fritz!fon, Gigaset, ...)
The handheld should contain:

Raspberry Pi Pico (RP2040)
LoRa Module
Display (LCD/OLED)

The plan is to power the handheld like a DECT phone with NiMH batteries.
I would like to use 3x AAA but depending on the power consumption, it would also be fine to use (2-3)x AA. The batteries shall be connected in series.
Now my problem is the charging circuit. The batteries should be charged, within the handheld, while powering the handheld itself, when put on the base station, like a DECT phone. It could happen that the handheld stays a long time on the base station (for days, weeks)
I have seen some schematics where a single cell will be hooked up directly (trickle charging).

But is this also applicable with 2 or 3 cells in series?
Can this be done while using the batteries? Or would it be in general better to switch the power source when charging to the "charging line"?
Would be overcharging an issue?


So I asked myself, how would a DECT phone do this, with a controller or special circuit?

would f. ex. the DS2715 be a good choice? (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ds2715.pdf)

This IC offers fast charging with 2C, but would this be beneficial or detrimental in such a use case?
Also which mode would be better Comparator Mode or Amplifier Mode?
How should the power be drawn from the batteries, directly or from somewhere within the charger circuit (looking at the reference circuits in the datasheet)?


Or would another charging circuit or IC's for this use case be better?

The project is still in the planning phase and the base station will be designed afterwards depending on the charging circuit. There are no requirements yet, except that it should be charged with DC.

Thank you very much.

After opening a Siemens Gigaset C59H I find the SC14440 CNF128VP WOF284.00 U0927 Chip. I do not find a datasheet for that specific Chip but for the SC14441 https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/sds/sc14441abc-sc14442a-short-form-datasheet This chip contains i.a. Charge Control for NiHM batteries
